# How to automate drag & drop functionality using Winium in java?

Tags: java, winium

I'm working in windows application automation and the drag and drop getting error...

```
public  void dragAndDrop() {

                WebElement ele=driver.findElementById("");
                WebElement ele1=driver.findElementByName("");



                  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                  Action dragDrop = action.dragAndDrop(ele, ele1).build();
                  dragDrop.perform();
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: 'mouseDown' is not
>   valid or implemented command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 27 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18
>   09:49:13 -0700' System info: host: 'AntonyW10', ip: '10.246.0.91',
>   os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '10.0.1' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver Capabilities
>   [{app=C:\Users\Antony\Downloads\setup.exe, args=, innerPort=9998,
>   debugConnectToRunningApp=false, keyboardSimulator=1, launchDelay=0,
>   platform=ANY}] Session ID: AwesomeSession

Comment: Any updates on this guys? I also encountered this issue. It seems that the Winium developers don't have plans on fixing the open issues. I want to contribute but don't know how to edit the package. Anyone who can advise or give ideas would be a great help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

Action dragDrop = action.clickAndHold(ele).moveToElement(ele1).release(ele1).build();

dragDrop.perform();
```

Comment: I tried but getting same error

Comment: I guess this is a default error present in Winium with Java. Please refer this below link              
https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/issues/69                                            This is a open issue in winium

Comment: here there is no solution mention

Comment: Yes. This is a open issue. They have to fix this to make your code work.

Comment: Check your import statements are correct for Action class import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong; try this:

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.dragAndDrop(ele1, ele2).build().perform();
```

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you were to explain how your code fixes the OP's problem.